# Syntax error postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a syntax error on **Postgresql**:

The error :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 19066: \.
            ^
********** Erreur **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
État SQL :42601
Caractère : 678313
```

And the offending line

```
COPY accesslog (aid, sid, title, path, url, hostname, uid, timer, "timestamp") FROM stdin;
\.
```

Do you have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: *Why* would you not show the actual error? What possible reason can there be for hiding it?

Comment: Sorry, I indicated the line affected by the error, but not the error in fact, here's the error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 19066: \.
            ^
********** Erreur **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
État SQL :42601
Caractère : 678313

Comment: @user3352128 Where are you executing this `copy` command ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Houari. I execute this command in pgadmin, to make a dump of my database

Answer (score 1):

PgAdmin-III doesn't support interactive line-by-line `COPY`. Use `psql`.

That said, I think you are trying to `COPY` data *FROM* the server, not to it.  If that's the case, either use `COPY ... TO 'some-file-name'` (a path relative to the database server), use `pg_dump`, or use `psql` with `\copy`.